# Running NetBeans on Ubuntu 13.10 with xmir enabled

Tags: unity, openjdk, netbeans, 13.10, mir

I have installed one of the latest daily build of saucy salamander. If I enable xmir java swing applications such as NetBeans or Oracle SQL Developer just display their splash screen but they don't display. They don't seem to freeze, because they are correctly listed in the process list. I am using an Intel chipset. 
More over, even with x fallback jayatana, which in previous ubuntu version worked as expected showing java applications menus in the global menubar, stopped working with both oracle java and open jdk.

This is what i see from startup log of oracle sqldeveloper 4 running on OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1515)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1804)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:131)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.(DragSource.java:147)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.dnd.JTreeDragHandler.(JTreeDragHandler.java:56)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorUI.setTree(NavigatorUI.java:148)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorWindow.createGUI(NavigatorWindow.java:107)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorWindow.getGUI(NavigatorWindow.java:319)
    at oracle.ide.docking.DockableWindow.getHostedComponent(DockableWindow.java:238)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbDockableContainer.componentOpened(NbDockableContainer.java:171)
    at org.openide.windows.WindowManager.componentOpenNotify(WindowManager.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.notifyTopComponentOpened(WindowManagerImpl.java:1140)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.addModeOpenedTopComponent(Central.java:798)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ModeImpl.addOpenedTopComponent(ModeImpl.java:354)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.initModeFromConfig(PersistenceHandler.java:451)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.load(PersistenceHandler.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:81)
    at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:231)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero occurred while creating cursor CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Cursor.java:362)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1513)
    ... 33 more
Failed to load a window
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.dnd.JTreeDragHandler.(JTreeDragHandler.java:56)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorUI.setTree(NavigatorUI.java:148)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorWindow.createGUI(NavigatorWindow.java:107)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.core.NavigatorWindow.getGUI(NavigatorWindow.java:319)
    at oracle.ide.docking.DockableWindow.getHostedComponent(DockableWindow.java:238)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbDockableContainer.componentOpened(NbDockableContainer.java:171)
    at org.openide.windows.WindowManager.componentOpenNotify(WindowManager.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.notifyTopComponentOpened(WindowManagerImpl.java:1140)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.addModeOpenedTopComponent(Central.java:798)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ModeImpl.addOpenedTopComponent(ModeImpl.java:354)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.initModeFromConfig(PersistenceHandler.java:451)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.load(PersistenceHandler.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:81)
    at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:231)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(DragSource.java:135)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.(DragSource.java:147)
    ... 30 more
Failed to load a window
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.dnd.DragSource
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.dnd.JTreeDragHandler.(JTreeDragHandler.java:56)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.createDragSource(BaseTreeExplorer.java:1477)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.createDragDropSupportIfEnabled(BaseTreeExplorer.java:1764)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.getTree(BaseTreeExplorer.java:1451)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.getJTree(BaseTreeExplorer.java:433)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator$NodeWatcher.(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:547)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator$NodeWatcher.(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:530)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator.registerOverlayConsumer(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:229)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator.processConsumerChangeEvent(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:209)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator.access$100(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:69)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCoordinator$4.stateChanged(IconOverlayCoordinator.java:187)
    at oracle.ide.explorer.IconOverlayCache.registerOverlayConsumer(IconOverlayCache.java:93)
    at oracle.ideri.navigator.DefaultNavigatorWindow.createTree(DefaultNavigatorWindow.java:1190)
    at oracle.ideri.navigator.DefaultNavigatorWindow.getGUI(DefaultNavigatorWindow.java:433)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.navigatorV2.ReportNavigatorWindow.init(ReportNavigatorWindow.java:36)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.navigatorV2.ReportNavigatorWindow.getGUI(ReportNavigatorWindow.java:64)
    at oracle.ide.docking.DockableWindow.getHostedComponent(DockableWindow.java:238)
    at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbDockableContainer.componentOpened(NbDockableContainer.java:171)
    at org.openide.windows.WindowManager.componentOpenNotify(WindowManager.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.notifyTopComponentOpened(WindowManagerImpl.java:1140)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.addModeOpenedTopComponent(Central.java:798)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ModeImpl.addOpenedTopComponent(ModeImpl.java:354)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.initModeFromConfig(PersistenceHandler.java:451)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.load(PersistenceHandler.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:81)
    at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:231)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Any suggestion. Thanks in advance

Andrea

Comment: Had the same problem: fix  is to sudo vim /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme and delete everything in there and save, then log out and log back in.